# How to get keyword id and ad group ad id from click_view?

Tags: google-ads-api

I'm migrating from Adwords API to Google Ads API. On Adwords API we have the click_performance_report which includes keyword id and ad group ad id. However, in Google Ads API, when querying using click_view, I can't find the corresponding fields. All I see is keyword and ad group ad fields but both return resource_name and I prefer not to parse it myself in order to get the id.
What's the best way to get the keyword id and ad group ad id using Google Ads API?

Answer (score 0):

About **group ad id** in your question:

`click_view` has `ad_group` as a segmenting resource ([docs](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/fields/v10/click_view)) which allows you to build the GAQL query:

```
  SELECT
    campaign.id,
    ad_group.id,
    click_view.keyword
  FROM click_view
  LIMIT 1
```

Unfortunately I don't have an answer on how to get **keyword id** without parsing the `click_view.keyword` field.